# Visual Studio shows Local Path but folder not mapped

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS, and I needed to move my folders on my local machine which was mapped to a different directory.  When remapping, I was having problems where the folder mappings were getting messed up badly as you could see in "Source Control Explorer" in Visual Studio.

As part of my attempts to fix it (after hours of trying), I removed all folders from the Workspace and removed all folder mapping from the root with recursive checked so nothing would be mapped and no local folders in workspace.  However a few subfolders in TFS still show their Local Path setting when viewed in "Source Control Explorer".

To make matters worse, when I try to "Map to Local Drive" in order to remove the setting, it says "The server folder is not mapped".  So it says it's not mapped but shows that it's mapped.

I've tried remapping the root again with recursive checked and the prior local path settings stay the same and the Workspace only shows the "root" as mapped.

As a side note, I do have multiple servers that I have to connect to in case that matters.

I'm unable to remove mapping on the folder, what do I do?  Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: After changing your mappings you **must** perform a get operation to make them effective. Until then it remains a mess.

Comment: During one of my attempts I did this and it placed the files in the local path that was wrong instead of the new one mapped relative to the root.  It preserved the wrong local path.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work.

The way I did it was by removing all mappings in the root as the original question stated, but for those folders that maintained local paths, I just mapped to a valid directory where I wanted them to be instead of the old path.

While doing this Visual Studio crashed (i'm sure that never happens).  I then restarted Visual Studio and then went back to the previous folders with the recently changed mappings and then removed mappings.  When I did this, it removed the mappings and said "not mapped".  I did this for all the the folders that were messed up.

After all folders were un-mapped, I mapped the root to where I wanted with recursive checked and the problem folders from before were mapped to the new directory.

I think the key was that I had to remove the mappings at the root and then remap the folders and then un-map them again.  Throw in a little "designed" crash by Microsoft's Visual Studio (sarcasm intended) and it worked.  Thanks for those that provided help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a remove mapping option if you right click on the project and go to advanced.

Comment: The option is to remove from the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to view your mappings? You can find all the working folders in your workspace and delete them.

If that doesn't help, try creating a new workspace.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not give this a try.  I wasn't sure if it was for those that administer TFS or the users.  I was able to solve my issue otherwise with a little luck.